# Removing Json elements from the Json array if some property is empty using jolt transform spec in nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a `JSON` payload:

```
{  
   "fields":[  
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"low",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"medium",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"high",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"blocker",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"",
         "value":"",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"",
         "value":"",
         "short":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove the array element if property `title` or `value` are empty. I am using Jolt transform processor. The o/p I required

```
{  
   "fields":[  
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"low",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"medium",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"high",
         "short":"true"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Priority",
         "value":"blocker",
         "short":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

And any place anyone can refer from where I can learn how to write spec would be very grateful. I have already referred https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove nodes first by `title` and after by `value`:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fields": {
        "*": {
          "title": {
            "": null,
            "*": {
              "@2": "fields[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fields": {
        "*": {
          "value": {
            "": null,
            "*": {
              "@2": "fields[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

See also:

- [How can I use “not equal” condition while filtering array using JOLT specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874578/how-can-i-use-not-equal-condition-while-filtering-array-using-jolt-specificati)

Comment: Thanks @Michal Ziober. This worked perfectly for me. :)

Comment: Great to hear that. Please take a look on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)